# Change Viewcontroller based on device orientation in iOS 8/9

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, segue

What is the preferred way of segueying between two viewcontrollers based on device orientation in iOS 8/9? I want to build an instrument that is shown in landscape. In portrait i want to show the settings of the App.

Comment: Why are you trying to segue instead of just hiding/showing different views on rotation?

Comment: I want to refactor the settings in future versions. So I think it makes sense to have two viewcontrollors. Right?

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't have 2 view controllers, but I wouldn't try to segue between them on rotations, because that will be slow and look bad. You can embed 2 container views in the main view controller and then just switch which ones are hidden.

Comment: That is a good idea. And what would you use to detect the rotation willTransitionToOrientation or the notification mentioned bellow?

Comment: All you really need to do is implement a rotation method or two. Then when they are called, perform whatever custom action you'd like. I think the documentation explains it pretty well: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate.swift inside the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" function I put:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

And then inside the AppDelegate class, put the following function:

```
func rotated(){
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation){            
        println("landscape")
    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)){
        println("Portrait")
    }
}
```

Or you can use this:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
        println("landscape")
    } else {
        println("portraight")
    }
}
```

Comment: The `viewWillTransitionToSize` implementation is the better one as it's avoid putting too much VC login in the appDelegate. Also, I believe it's the newer way of doing it and I've had good results with it performing rotations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my mechanism I created for iOS 9, but this should also work for iOS 8 as well.

```
import UIKit

extension CGSize {

    static func minMaxSize(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: size.minValue(), height: size.maxValue())
    }

    static func maxMinSize(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: size.maxValue(), height: size.minValue())
    }

    func minValue() -> CGFloat {

        return min(self.width, self.height)
    }

    func maxValue() -> CGFloat {

        return max(self.width, self.height)
    }
}

extension UIScreen {

    func isPortrait() -> Bool {

        return self.bounds.width < self.bounds.height
    }
}

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    var verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    private lazy var _isPortrait: Bool = UIScreen.mainScreen().isPortrait()

    func isPortrait() -> Bool {

        if let parentViewController = self.parentViewController as? BaseViewController {

            return parentViewController.isPortrait()
        }

        return _isPortrait
    }

    override func loadView() {

        self.view = UIView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.addViewController()

        self.addLayoutGuides()
        self.setupLayoutGuides()

        self.addSubViews()
        self.setupSubViews()
    }

    func addViewController() {

        /* override point */
    }

    func addLayoutGuides() {

        /* override point */
    }

    func setupLayoutGuides() {

        /* override point */
    }

    func addSubViews() {

        /* override point */
    }

    func setupSubViews() {

        /* override point */
    }

    private func applyConstraints() {

        self.willApplyConstraints()

        self.isPortrait() ? self.applyVerticalConstrains() : self.applyHorizontalConstrains()

        self.didApllyedConstraints()
    }

    func willApplyConstraints() {

        /* override point */
    }

    func applyVerticalConstrains() {

        /* override point */
    }

    func applyHorizontalConstrains() {

        /* override point */
    }

    func didApllyedConstraints() {

        /* override point */


    override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        if let superView = self.view.superview {

            if superView.isKindOfClass(UIWindow.self) && self.parentViewController == nil {

                if CGSize.minMaxSize(size) == CGSize.minMaxSize(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size) {

                    _isPortrait = size.width < size.height
                }
            }
        }

        super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

        self.applyConstraints()
    }
}
```

At least I assume that the child viewController will never touch inherited private `_isPortrait`, because it is `lazy`. Only the top level view can of the `rootViewController` is allowed to set this property. The super `viewWillTransitionToSize` function is called after the check is done. So if the value was set on the `rootViewController`, all child viewController will have the correct value at the time their `viewWillTransitionToSize` function is called. This has to be done, because you can not rely on the the size of the child viewController views, but at least you can trust your `rootViewController if it is fullscreen. Hope that will help someone somehow.

So my `RootViewController` may look like this now.

```
class RootViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func addViewController() {

        /* add child view controller here so they can receive callbacks */
    }

    override func addSubViews() {

        /* add your subviews here in a way you like so you can play with AutoLayout as you wish */
    }

    override func setupSubViews() {

        /* setup up your views here and always activate vertical constraints here */
        /* because iOS will always initialize in portrait even if launched in landscape */
        /* deactivate your horizontal constrains and put them inside the array */
        /* add vertical constraints to the vertical array; other constraints can be active */
        /* without the need to be added somewhere */
    }

    override func willApplyConstraints() {

        /* deactivate all constrains */
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.verticalConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.horizontalConstraints)
    }

    override func applyVerticalConstrains() {

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(self.verticalConstraints)
    }

    override func applyHorizontalConstrains() {

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(self.horizontalConstraints)
    }

    override func didApllyedConstraints() {

        /* force layouting if needed */
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE (Xcode 7 - OS X 10.11.1 beta):** For iPad testing use iPad 2 or iPad Retina simulator, because the Air 1/2 are broken with AutoLayout. All simulators will produce this message: `<CATransformLayer: 0x790af320> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect`