# How do I properly lock my viewController in a specific orientation in swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I want to lock my viewController in portrait mode, i tried using the following lines, but they haven't worked:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        let orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown]

        return orientation
    }
```

how do I properly achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to just have that one orientation for your app, follow these steps.

1. Go to the left-most pane of Xcode (it's called the Project Navigator) and select the topmost icon that is named the name of your app.
2. The editor section will change to your app's settings and configurations. Select "General"
3. Scroll down to near the bottom to "Deployment Info". Under that section is the "Device Orientation" section.
4. Click the required orientations

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460049/change-viewcontroller-based-on-device-orientation-in-ios-8-9 - this doesn't have an accepted answer yet, but there are 2 answers that should help you.